# Transform original Json using Play Framework in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following Json:

```
{"id": 1,
"url":[
   {"format":""},
   {"creator":""},
   {"value":"http://..."}
 ]
}
```

How can I transform it into `"url": "http://..."`.

How can I do this? I tried the following, but it does not seem to be working.

`(json \ "value").as[JsString].value`

Comment: You're question is unclear, because you're expecting a single url on the output, while your input json contains an array of urls. So what are you really trying to achieve here? A single (url, urlValue) pair (in this case your json is invalid) or a `List` of pairs (in this case your expectation is invalid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "url" has an array value, you need to index it appropriately to get the value you require, so in your case it would be something like:

```
scala> val url = (json \ "url")(2).get
url: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"value":"http://..."}

scala> (url \ "value").as[String]
res22: String = http://...
```

I also recommend looking at [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/) if you are comfortable with a more functional approach for dealing with JSON. It is much superior to the JSON facilities provided by Play.